# JQuery .change(function) not working in DataTables 2nd page and after

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am using Jquery data-table and using select tag which is dependent on table , but Jquery script doesn't work on second page and after. I want to filter results in table based on select tag in all pages but as soon as I choose option from select tag it only filters the rows present in the first page and for the remaining pages again I have to use select tag. I am sharing code snippet. Please provide some suggestion to make it work for all rows at any page .

```
<body>
    <select id="cato" class="form-control" >
        <option disabled selected="true">-Select Category-</option>
        <option>Electronics</option>
        <option>Sports</option>
    </select>

    <table class="table table-bordered" id="example"  data-order='[[ 0, "desc" ]]' data-page-length='3'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Subcategory</th>
                <th>Category</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="r">
            <tr>
                <td>Samsung</td>
                <td>Mobile</td>
                <td>Electronics</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Racket</td>
                <td>Tennis</td>
                <td>Sports</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bat</td>
                <td>Cricket</td>
                <td>Sports</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dell</td>
                <td>Laptop</td>
                <td>Electronics</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Iphone</td>
                <td>Mobile</td>
                <td>Electronics</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

**Table**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "bLengthChange": false,
        searching: false,
  });
  </script>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>   
$('#cato').on('change', function() {
  var filter, table, tr, td, i;
  filter=$("#cato option:selected").text().toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("r");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];          
    if (td) { 
      if ((td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1))
      {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      }
       else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for a different approach.

Look at my example:

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  "bLengthChange": false,
  pageLength: 2,
  dom: 'tip'
});
  
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        
        var filter= $("#cato option:selected").text().toUpperCase();
        var subCategory = String(data[2]).toUpperCase();
 
        if ( filter == subCategory )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
);
  
$('#cato').on('change', function() {
  table.draw()
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<select id="cato" class="form-control">
  <option disabled selected="true">-Select Category-</option>
  <option>Electronics</option>
  <option>Sports</option>
</select>

<table id="example" class="table display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Subcategory</th>
      <th>Category</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="r">
    <tr>
      <td>Samsung</td>
      <td>Mobile</td>
      <td>Electronics</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Racket</td>
      <td>Tennis</td>
      <td>Sports</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bat</td>
      <td>Cricket</td>
      <td>Sports</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dell</td>
      <td>Laptop</td>
      <td>Electronics</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Iphone</td>
      <td>Mobile</td>
      <td>Electronics</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Soccer Ball</td>
      <td>Soccer</td>
      <td>Sports</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Important:** In order for `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(` to work properly, the jQuery DataTable `searching` option must be **true** (its default value), otherwise it won't work. But if you don't want to use the default search box or even hide it, you could use the:

**[dom property](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)**

In my example I used the value `tip`. As you can see in the above link...

***t*** - is the ***t***able itself
***i*** - is Table ***i***nformation summary
***p*** - is ***p***agination control

Comment: Thanks for the edit and answer, it worked like a charm .I spent some time to figure it out to hide search :). I hided it out by using display:none property. Can you help me out with this question which is an enhancement of your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63373311/filter-table-dependent-on-multiple-select-tags