# Filter table dependent on Multiple select tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using Jquery datatable and I want to use multiple select tags to filter datatable but currently I am able to filter using 1 select tag. One select tag is for one column and the another select tag is for another column. Both select tag should work in "OR" and "AND" condition to filter datatable. I am sharing code snippet. Please provide some suggestion to make it work .

**HTML**

```
<select id="cato" class="form-control">
  <option disabled selected="true">-Select Category-</option>
  <option>Electronics</option>
  <option>Sports</option>
</select>

<select id="subo" class="form-control">
   <option disabled selected="true">-Select Subcategory-</option>
   <option>Laptop</option>
   <option>Mobile</option>
 </select>

<table id="example" class="table display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Subcategory</th>
      <th>Category</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="r">
    <tr>
      <td>Samsung</td>
      <td>Mobile</td>
      <td>Electronics</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Racket</td>
      <td>Tennis</td>
      <td>Sports</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bat</td>
      <td>Cricket</td>
      <td>Sports</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dell</td>
      <td>Laptop</td>
      <td>Electronics</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Iphone</td>
      <td>Mobile</td>
      <td>Electronics</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Soccer Ball</td>
      <td>Soccer</td>
      <td>Sports</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  "bLengthChange": false,
  pageLength: 3,
  dom: 'tip'
});
  
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {        
        var filter= $("#cato option:selected").text().toUpperCase();
        var subCategory = String(data[2]).toUpperCase(); 
        if ( filter == subCategory )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
);  
$('#cato').on('change', function() {
  table.draw()
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  "bLengthChange": false,
  //searching: false,
  pageLength: 2,
  dom: 'tip'
});
  
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
    
    var filterCategory= $("#cato option:selected").text().toUpperCase();
    var filterSubCategory= $("#subo option:selected").text().toUpperCase();
    var subCategory = String(data[1]).toUpperCase();
    var category = String(data[2]).toUpperCase();
    
    //console.log(filterSubCategory);
    
    if(filterSubCategory != "-SELECT SUBCATEGORY-") {
        if ( filterCategory == category && filterSubCategory == subCategory)
             return true;
        }
        else if(filterCategory != "-SELECT CATEGORY-") {
            if ( filterCategory == category)
             return true;
        }
  
        return false;
    }
);

$('#cato').on('change', function() {
  $('#subo').val("");
  table.draw();
});

$('#subo').on('change', function() {
  table.draw();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<select id="cato" class="form-control" >
  <option value="" disabled selected="true">-Select Category-</option>
  <option>Electronics</option>
  <option>Sports</option>
</select>

<select id="subo" class="form-control">
   <option value="" disabled selected="true">-Select Subcategory-</option>
   <option>Laptop</option>
   <option>Mobile</option>
</select>

<table id="example" class="table display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Subcategory</th>
      <th>Category</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="r">
    <tr>
      <td>Samsung</td>
      <td>Mobile</td>
      <td>Electronics</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Racket</td>
      <td>Tennis</td>
      <td>Sports</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bat</td>
      <td>Cricket</td>
      <td>Sports</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dell</td>
      <td>Laptop</td>
      <td>Electronics</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Iphone</td>
      <td>Mobile</td>
      <td>Electronics</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Soccer Ball</td>
      <td>Soccer</td>
      <td>Sports</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use Datatable colums filtering: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html

Comment: Thanks for reply but I am using multiple select tags and column filtering would work for single column only

Answer (score 0):

If your code works, simply add the other filter

```
function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {        
        var filterCato= $("#cato option:selected").text().toUpperCase();
        var filterSubo= $("#subo option:selected").text().toUpperCase();

        var category = String(data[2]).toUpperCase(); 
        var subCategory = String(data[1]).toUpperCase(); 
        
        if ( filterSubo == subCategory || filterCato==category )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```